# Difference between `nditer` and `flat`, type of element

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I created subplots and I wanted to modify `xlim` for each of subplot. I wrote the following code to do that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(20, 10))

for ax in np.nditer(axs, flags=['refs_ok']):
    ax.set_xlim(left=0.0, right=0.5)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'
```

I did a bit more research and ended up with using `flat` to achieve what I wanted in the first place. But I do not understand why `nditer` is not working as I would expect. To illustrate it - the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(20, 10))

print("Using flat")
for ax in axs.flat:
    print(ax, type(ax))

print("Using nditer")
for ax in np.nditer(axs, flags=['refs_ok']):
    print(ax, type(ax))
```

gives this results:

```
Using flat
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.536818;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.536818;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.536818;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.125;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.125;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>

Using nditer
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.536818;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.536818;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.536818;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.125;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.125;0.227941x0.343182) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

As I understand `plt.subplots` return 2D array and preferred method to iterate over its elements is `nditer` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html). Why then it does not work in this case and element that I am iterating over has type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` rather than `<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>`?

Comment: The `nditer` docs are misleading. In `c` code `nditer` is preferred, in python code it is usually slower and harder to use right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over an array with `nditer` gives you views of the original array's cells as 0-dimensional arrays. For non-object arrays, this is almost equivalent to producing scalars, since 0-dimensional arrays usually behave like scalars, but that doesn't work for object arrays.

Iterating over an object array with `flat` just gives you the objects directly.

Comment: Thanks. That's explains it. So in order to get access to object, I can use `item`. Right?

Comment: @Grzegorz: Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

@Grzegorz

If you want to get the value through `nditer`, use the `tolist` method

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(20, 10))

print("Using flat")
for ax in axs.flat:
    print(ax, type(ax))

print("Using nditer")
for ax in np.nditer(axs, flags=['refs_ok']):
    b = ax.tolist()
    print(b, type(b))
```

gives this results:

```py
Using flat
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.53;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.53;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.53;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.11;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.11;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
Using nditer
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.53;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.53;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.53;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.398529,0.11;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
AxesSubplot(0.672059,0.11;0.227941x0.35) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```